# Geodataframe map plot seems to ignore legend_kwds

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm trying to edit the legend parameters of a map plot using a geodataframe. My problem is that the legend_kwds seemed to be ignored.

Thank you in advance for your time!!

The graph code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
Q= Valores.plot(column=Columna_Criterio, ax=ax, cmap = 'viridis', linewidth=0, legend=True, legend_kwds={'fontsize':'xx-small','label': "Population by Country", 'orientation': "horizontal"})
ax.axis('off')
```

The result is this graph:

[The cmap and linewidth parameters are modifying the graph, while the legend_kwds are not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMPVQ.png)+

If I delete the legend_kwds parameters:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
Q= Valores.plot(column=Columna_Criterio, ax=ax, cmap = 'viridis', linewidth=0, legend=True)
ax.axis('off')
```

The result is exactly the same.... 
[Is the same...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZOm.png)

Do you know what is wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

After successfully updating geopandas to 0.6.1 ... I'm having still the same problem... the graph doesn't change with the legend_kwds parameters.

I used @swatchai code suggestion and I was able to modify the labels letter size but not the bar position.

Thank you again in advance for your time!!

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py37_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
anaconda                  2019.10                  py37_0  
anaconda-client           1.7.2                    py37_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.9.7                    py37_0  
anaconda-project          0.8.3                      py_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
appscript                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
asn1crypto                1.0.1                    py37_0  
astroid                   2.3.1                    py37_0  
astropy                   3.2.2            py37h1de35cc_0  
atomicwrites              1.3.0                    py37_1  
attrs                     19.2.0                     py_0  
babel                     2.7.0                      py_0  
backcall                  0.1.0                    py37_0  
backports                 1.0                        py_2  
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.5                        py_2  
backports.os              0.1.1                    py37_0  
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                    py37_2  
backports.tempfile        1.0                        py_1  
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
beautifulsoup4            4.8.0                    py37_0  
bitarray                  1.0.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
bkcharts                  0.2                      py37_0  
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    3.1.0                    py37_0  
blosc                     1.16.3               hd9629dc_0  
bokeh                     1.3.4                    py37_0  
boto                      2.49.0                   py37_0  
bottleneck                1.2.1            py37h1d22016_1  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h1de35cc_0  
ca-certificates           2019.8.28                     0  
cairo                     1.14.12              hc4e6be7_4  
certifi                   2019.9.11                py37_0  
cffi                      1.12.3           py37hb5b8e2f_0  
chardet                   3.0.4                 py37_1003  
click                     7.0                      py37_0  
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0  
cligj                     0.5.0                    py37_0  
cloudpickle               1.2.2                      py_0  
clyent                    1.2.2                    py37_1  
colorama                  0.4.1                    py37_0  
conda                     4.7.12                   py37_0  
conda-build               3.18.9                   py37_3  
conda-env                 2.6.0                         1  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
contextlib2               0.6.0                      py_0  
cryptography              2.7              py37ha12b0ac_0  
curl                      7.65.3               ha441bb4_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py37_0  
cython                    0.29.13          py37h0a44026_0  
cytoolz                   0.10.0           py37h1de35cc_0  
dask                      2.5.2                      py_0  
dask-core                 2.5.2                      py_0  
dbus                      1.13.6               h90a0687_0  
decorator                 4.4.0                    py37_1  
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0  
deprecated                1.2.6                    pypi_0    pypi
descartes                 1.1.0                      py_3  
distributed               2.5.2                      py_0  
docutils                  0.15.2                   py37_0  
entrypoints               0.3                      py37_0  
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py37_0  
expat                     2.2.6                h0a44026_0  
fastcache                 1.1.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
filelock                  3.0.12                     py_0  
fiona                     1.8.4            py37h9a122fd_0  
flask                     1.1.1                      py_0  
fontconfig                2.13.0               h5d5b041_1  
freetype                  2.9.1                hb4e5f40_0  
freexl                    1.0.5                h1de35cc_0  
fsspec                    0.5.2                      py_0  
future                    0.17.1                   py37_0  
gdal                      2.3.3            py37hbe65578_0  
geopandas                 0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
geos                      3.7.1                h0a44026_0  
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h7520d66_0  
gettext                   0.19.8.1             h15daf44_3  
gevent                    1.4.0            py37h1de35cc_0  
giflib                    5.1.4                h1de35cc_1  
glib                      2.56.2               hd9629dc_0  
glob2                     0.7                        py_0  
gmp                       6.1.2                hb37e062_1  
gmpy2                     2.0.8            py37h6ef4df4_2  
greenlet                  0.4.15           py37h1de35cc_0  
h5py                      2.9.0            py37h3134771_0  
hdf4                      4.2.13               h39711bb_2  
hdf5                      1.10.4               hfa1e0ec_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
html5lib                  1.0.1                    py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 h4b95b61_1  
idna                      2.8                      py37_0  
imageio                   2.6.0                    py37_0  
imagesize                 1.1.0                    py37_0  
importlib_metadata        0.23                     py37_0  
intel-openmp              2019.4                      233  
ipykernel                 5.1.2            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython                   7.8.0            py37h39e3cac_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0  
isort                     4.3.21                   py37_0  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jbig                      2.1                  h4d881f8_0  
jdcal                     1.4.1                      py_0  
jedi                      0.15.1                   py37_0  
jinja2                    2.10.3                     py_0  
joblib                    0.13.2                   py37_0  
jpeg                      9b                   he5867d9_2  
json-c                    0.13.1               h3efe00b_0  
json5                     0.8.5                      py_0  
jsonschema                3.0.2                    py37_0  
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7  
jupyter_client            5.3.3                    py37_1  
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0  
jupyter_core              4.5.0                      py_0  
jupyterlab                1.1.4              pyhf63ae98_0  
jupyterlab_server         1.0.6                      py_0  
kealib                    1.4.7                hf5ed860_6  
keyring                   18.0.0                   py37_0  
kiwisolver                1.1.0            py37h0a44026_0  
krb5                      1.16.1               hddcf347_7  
lazy-object-proxy         1.4.2            py37h1de35cc_0  
libarchive                3.3.3                h786848e_5  
libboost                  1.67.0               hebc422b_4  
libcurl                   7.65.3               h051b688_0  
libcxx                    4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libcxxabi                 4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
libdap4                   3.19.1               h3d3e54a_0  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hb402a30_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                h475c297_4  
libgdal                   2.3.3                h0950a36_0  
libgfortran               3.0.1                h93005f0_2  
libiconv                  1.15                 hdd342a3_7  
libkml                    1.3.0                hbe12b63_4  
liblief                   0.9.0                h2a1bed3_2  
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                hd5207e6_2  
libpng                    1.6.37               ha441bb4_0  
libpq                     11.2                 h051b688_0  
libsodium                 1.0.16               h3efe00b_0  
libspatialindex           1.8.5                h2c08c6b_2  
libspatialite             4.3.0a              h644ec7d_19  
libssh2                   1.8.2                ha12b0ac_0  
libtiff                   4.0.10               hcb84e12_2  
libxml2                   2.9.9                hf6e021a_1  
libxslt                   1.1.33               h33a18ac_0  
llvm-openmp               4.0.1                hcfea43d_1  
llvmlite                  0.29.0           py37h98b8051_0  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lxml                      4.4.1            py37hef8c89e_0  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h1de35cc_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h362108e_2  
mapclassify               2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h1de35cc_0  
matplotlib                3.1.1            py37h54f8f79_0  
mccabe                    0.6.1                    py37_1  
mistune                   0.8.4            py37h1de35cc_0  
mkl                       2019.4                      233  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37hfbe908c_0  
mkl_fft                   1.0.14           py37h5e564d8_0  
mkl_random                1.1.0            py37ha771720_0  
mock                      3.0.5                    py37_0  
more-itertools            7.2.0                    py37_0  
mpc                       1.1.0                h6ef4df4_1  
mpfr                      4.0.1                h3018a27_3  
mpmath                    1.1.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37h04f5b5a_1  
multipledispatch          0.6.0                    py37_0  
munch                     2.3.2                    py37_0  
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py37_0  
nbconvert                 5.6.0                    py37_1  
nbformat                  4.4.0                    py37_0  
ncurses                   6.1                  h0a44026_1  
networkx                  2.3                        py_0  
nltk                      3.4.5                    py37_0  
nose                      1.3.7                    py37_2  
notebook                  6.0.1                    py37_0  
numba                     0.45.1           py37h6440ff4_0  
numexpr                   2.7.0            py37h7413580_0  
numpy                     1.17.2           py37h99e6662_0  
numpy-base                1.17.2           py37h6575580_0  
numpydoc                  0.9.1                      py_0  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openjpeg                  2.3.0                hb95cd4c_1  
openpyxl                  3.0.0                      py_0  
openssl                   1.1.1d               h1de35cc_2  
packaging                 19.2                       py_0  
pandas                    0.25.1           py37h0a44026_0  
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0  
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py37_1  
parso                     0.5.1                      py_0  
partd                     1.0.0                      py_0  
path.py                   12.0.1                     py_0  
pathlib2                  2.3.5                    py37_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pcre                      8.43                 h0a44026_0  
pep8                      1.7.1                    py37_0  
pexpect                   4.7.0                    py37_0  
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py37_0  
pillow                    6.2.0            py37hb68e598_0  
pip                       19.2.3                   py37_0  
pixman                    0.38.0               h1de35cc_0  
pkginfo                   1.5.0.1                  py37_0  
pluggy                    0.13.0                   py37_0  
ply                       3.11                     py37_0  
poppler                   0.65.0               ha097c24_1  
poppler-data              0.4.9                         0  
proj4                     5.2.0                h0a44026_1  
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0  
prompt_toolkit            2.0.10                     py_0  
psutil                    5.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
psycopg2                  2.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.6.0                    py37_0  
py                        1.8.0                    py37_0  
py-lief                   0.9.0            py37h1413db1_2  
pycodestyle               2.5.0                    py37_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
pycparser                 2.19                     py37_0  
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py37h1de35cc_9  
pycurl                    7.43.0.3         py37ha12b0ac_0  
pyflakes                  2.1.1                    py37_0  
pygments                  2.4.2                      py_0  
pylint                    2.4.2                    py37_0  
pyodbc                    4.0.27           py37h0a44026_0  
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py37_0  
pyparsing                 2.4.2                      py_0  
pyproj                    2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py37h655552a_2  
pyrsistent                0.15.4           py37h1de35cc_0  
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_0  
pytables                  3.5.2            py37h5bccee9_1  
pytest                    5.2.1                    py37_0  
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0  
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0  
pytest-doctestplus        0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-openfiles          0.4.0                      py_0  
pytest-remotedata         0.3.2                    py37_0  
python                    3.7.4                h359304d_1  
python-dateutil           2.8.0                    py37_0  
python-libarchive-c       2.8                     py37_13  
python.app                2                        py37_9  
pytz                      2019.3                     py_0  
pywavelets                1.0.3            py37h1d22016_1  
pyyaml                    5.1.2            py37h1de35cc_0  
pyzmq                     18.1.0           py37h0a44026_0  
qt                        5.9.7                h468cd18_1  
qtawesome                 0.6.0                      py_0  
qtconsole                 4.5.5                      py_0  
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0  
readline                  7.0                  h1de35cc_5  
requests                  2.22.0                   py37_0  
ripgrep                   0.10.0               hc07d326_0  
rope                      0.14.0                     py_0  
rtree                     0.8.3                    py37_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.46          py37h1de35cc_0  
scikit-image              0.15.0           py37h0a44026_0  
scikit-learn              0.21.3           py37h27c97d8_0  
scipy                     1.3.1            py37h1410ff5_0  
seaborn                   0.9.0                    py37_0  
send2trash                1.5.0                    py37_0  
setuptools                41.4.0                   py37_0  
shapely                   1.6.4            py37he8793f5_0  
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py37_2  
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py37_0  
sip                       4.19.8           py37h0a44026_0  
six                       1.12.0                   py37_0  
snappy                    1.1.7                he62c110_3  
snowballstemmer           2.0.0                      py_0  
sortedcollections         1.1.2                    py37_0  
sortedcontainers          2.1.0                    py37_0  
soupsieve                 1.9.3                    py37_0  
sphinx                    2.2.0                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib             1.0                      py37_1  
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.2                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.3                      py_0  
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.2                      py_0  
spyder                    3.3.6                    py37_0  
spyder-kernels            0.5.2                    py37_0  
sqlalchemy                1.3.9            py37h1de35cc_0  
sqlite                    3.30.0               ha441bb4_0  
statsmodels               0.10.1           py37h1d22016_0  
sympy                     1.4                      py37_0  
tbb                       2019.8               h04f5b5a_0  
tblib                     1.4.0                      py_0  
terminado                 0.8.2                    py37_0  
testpath                  0.4.2                    py37_0  
tk                        8.6.8                ha441bb4_0  
toolz                     0.10.0                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.3            py37h1de35cc_0  
tqdm                      4.36.1                     py_0  
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py37_0  
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py37_0  
unixodbc                  2.3.7                h1de35cc_0  
urllib3                   1.24.2                   py37_0  
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py37_0  
webencodings              0.5.1                    py37_1  
werkzeug                  0.16.0                     py_0  
wheel                     0.33.6                   py37_0  
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0  
wrapt                     1.11.2           py37h1de35cc_0  
wurlitzer                 1.0.3                    py37_0  
xerces-c                  3.2.2                h44e365a_0  
xlrd                      1.2.0                    py37_0  
xlsxwriter                1.2.1                      py_0  
xlwings                   0.15.10                  py37_0  
xlwt                      1.3.0                    py37_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h1de35cc_4  
yaml                      0.1.7                hc338f04_2  
zeromq                    4.3.1                h0a44026_3  
zict                      1.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      0.6.0                      py_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h1de35cc_3  
zstd                      1.3.7                h5bba6e5_0
```

Comment: What version of GeoPandas are you using? (you can check `geopandas.__version__`) The ability to modify the colorbar through `legend_kwds` was only added in the latest release (0.6).

Comment: Thanks joris, I tried unsuccessfully to update my GeoPandas... please take a look to the question update

Comment: Ideally install geopandas from conda-forge http://geopandas.org/install.html#using-the-conda-forge-channel

Answer (score 4):

You need to upgrade geopandas to v 0.6. Then try running this modified code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas
import matplotlib

# set font size here
matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 7

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[9,6])

# --- more lines of code here ---

Q = Valores.plot(column=Columna_Criterio, ax=ax, cmap = 'viridis', \
    linewidth=0, legend=True, \
    legend_kwds={'label': "Population by Country", 'orientation': "horizontal"})

ax.axis('off')
```

**Edit**

Here is the runnable code using the world data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas

import matplotlib
# set font size
matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 7

# make use of the provided world dataset
world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

# drop some rows
world = world[(world.name != "Antarctica") & (world.name != "Fr. S. Antarctic Lands")]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=[9,6])

myplot = world.plot(column='pop_est',
                ax=ax, legend=True, 
                legend_kwds={'label': "Population by Country", 
                             'orientation': "horizontal"})
```

The output plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks swatchai, I tried unsuccessfully to update my GeoPandas... please take a look to the question update

Comment: Thanks for your time @swatchai, It didn't work... I even try running your code exactly as it is in the post and the bar appears vertical... I think is a problem with my python installation... A few days ago I upgrade my Mac OS to Catalina and since then I've been having a lot of problems...